# Help in using sed

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have a file named 'custom.conf'

inside this file I have

```
[globals]


[guest]
```

What I want to do is insert this line after [globals]

```
#include = HKRoomStat.conf
#include = HKRoomStatFuncODBC.conf
```

and Insert this line after [guest]

```
include = room_stat
```

I have this code

```
sed  -i '/'[globals]'/a #include = HKRoomStat.conf' custom.conf
sed  -i '/#include = HKRoomStat.conf/a #include = HKRoomStatFuncODBC.conf' custom.conf
sed  -i '/'[guest]'/a include = room_stat' custom.conf
```

but when I run this on the cli I instead get this result

```
[globals]
include = room_stat
#include = HKRoomStat.conf
include = room_stat
#include = HKRoomStatFuncODBC.conf
include = room_stat

[guest]
include = room_stat
#include = HKRoomStat.conf
include = room_stat
#include = HKRoomStatFuncODBC.conf
include = room_stat
```

I'm just beginning to learn sed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advanced

Comment: You are walking on thin ice when you weave in n out of quotes. Specifically, `[globals]` is unquoted and has [] characters, hence subject to filename expansion. You're lucky you don't have files named g l o b a s (even one will do). Then your sed code is going to misfire bigtime, as characters g/l/o/b/a/s can occur just about on any line and the append will happen in all of them, leaving behind a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to append line(s) is via the `a\` command of sed. This way is visually very informative as to how many lines are to be added and what all they are.

```
sed -i -e '
  /\[globals]/a\
#include = HKRoomStat.conf\
#include = HKRoomStatFuncODBC.conf

  /\[guest]/a\
include = room_stat
' custom.conf
```

Comment: This worked! thanks